# Phongap Socialsharing plugin - ipad screen positioning not working

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build, socialshare

Since updating the ipad from ios7 to ios8, my phonegap social sharing plugin doesn't position correctly on the ipad screen. It just appears narrow rather than applying the position/coordinates that I've set in the code.  Any ideas on how to solve this issue please? Or has anybody encountered this problem before?

Plugin version: `gap:plugin name="nl.x-services.plugins.socialsharing" version="4.3.8"`

The script below is used in my html page to position the share box.

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener(
    'deviceready',
    function() {
    window.plugins.socialsharing.iPadPopupCoordinates = function() {

    return "100,200,300,300";
    };
    },
    false);
</script>
```

This is what calls the plugin on the share button. This works fine as the share box does appear on the ipad screen.

```
<a href="#" class="ui-button-action" onclick="window.plugins.socialsharing.share(' ', '')">
```

Many Thanks

Comment: seems like a bug, open an issue on the plugin's github page

Comment: Thanks, but somebody else already did, but it's still not been resolved. https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin/issues/272     I thought that somebody here might have experienced the same issue and had a good workaround.  Thank you